# Jquery - Toggle button class and action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create toggle button onclick writing localstorage and also switching class on the fly without refreshing the page. it works somehow like a checkbox. here's the code:

```
....
document.write("<button id='wawa_"+i+"'");
   if (!checked) {
   document.write("class='buttons uncheck' onClick='clickYes("+i+")'");
   } else {
    document.write("class='buttons check' onClick='clickNo("+i+")'");   
   }

   document.write(">cek</button>");
   document.write("</td></tr>");


  }

  document.write("</table>");

    function clickYes(x) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("selected"+x, x);   
    alert("yeaaaahhh"); }


    function clickNo(x) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem("selected"+x);
    alert("noooo");

    }
```

Using this code, it cannot change on the fly. **The data is saved, but if you want to delete data, you have to refresh the page (because the button action doesn't change).** Im working on a scheduler app.

Comment: That's good news, any question?

Comment: sorry, edited with question...

Comment: If you want to remove the item **off the page** you need to actually remove the item off the page. Just removing it out of localstorage only removes the localstorage item, not the DOM element. These are two entirely different things.

Comment: You should try using the DOM instead of writing the HTML to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try working with DOM elements instead of writing the HTML to your document.
Also... try not to "hardcode" values as parameters :(

instead you could...

```
...
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.className = 'buttons uncheck';
    btn.setAttribute('data-index', i);
    btn.setAttribute('data-checked', false);
    btn.onclick = function() {clickAction()}

    document.getElementById('your-table-id').append(btn);
}

function clickAction() {
    var x = this.getAttribute('data-index');
    if (this.getAttribute('data-checked') == 'false') {
        localStorage.setItem("selected" + x, x);
        btn.setAttribute('data-checked', true);
        this.className = 'buttons check';
        alert("noooo");
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("selected" + x);
        btn.setAttribute('data-checked', false);
        this.className = 'buttons uncheck';
        alert("yeeeees");
    }
}
```

I think this should work, it's not the best code you could get, but try to understand how to work with DOM, and then when you understand it, try using JQuery or Zepto, those would help you a lot.

Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM for more info.

Comment: ok thanks, really helps, i just learning java script, so still a bit confused.